# MapStruct: how to map list of objects where as source is having only one object

Tags: mapstruct

New to MapStruct and I am trying to map list of objects in target class where as source is having individual values including other String variables. No luck with custom implementation also. Any suggestions pleas to implement

```
public class Source {
   String var1;
   String var2;
   String resourceCd1;
   String resourceCd2;
   String resourceCd3;
   String resourceCd4;
   String resourceCd5;
   String resourceDesc1;
   String resourceDesc2;
   String resourceDesc3;
   String resourceDesc4;
   String resourceDesc5;
   String var3;
   String var4;
}

public class Target {
   List<Resource> resources;
}

public class Resource {
   String code;
   String description;
}
```

Expectation is to have list of Resource objects including code and description values like below in Target.

```
List<Resource> resources = new ArrayList<>();

    Resource resource1 = new Resource();
    resource1.code = soruce.resourceCd1;
    resource1.description = soruce.resourceDesc1;
    resources.add(resource1);

    Resource resource2 = new Resource();
    resource2.code = soruce.resourceCd2;
    resource2.description = soruce.resourceDesc2;
    resources.add(resource2);

    Resource resource3 = new Resource();
    resource3.code = soruce.resourceCd3;
    resource3.description = soruce.resourceDesc3;
    resources.add(resource3);


    Resource resource4 = new Resource();
    resource4.code = soruce.resourceCd4;
    resource4.description = soruce.resourceDesc4;
    resources.add(resource4);

    Resource resource5 = new Resource();
    resource5.code = soruce.resourceCd5;
    resource5.description = soruce.resourceDesc5;
    resources.add(resource5);
```

Here resourceCd1,..,resourceCd5 and resourceDesc1,..,resourceDesc5 are from the source class

Answer (score 1):

Not possible with MapStruct out of the box. MapStruct supports bean-to-bean, iterable-to-iterable, map-to-map.

Currently under construction: [bean-to-map](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/pull/1744) .. When ready you could convert the map to a list by means of a stream / collector.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface SourceMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "resources", qualifiedByName = "mapResources")
    Target toTarget(Source source);

    @Named("mapResources") 
    default List<Resource> mapResources(Source source){
        List<Resource> resources = new ArrayList<>();

        Resource resource1 = new Resource();
        resource1.setCode(source.getResourceCd1());
        resource1.setDescription(source.getResourceDesc1());
        resources.add(resource1);

        Resource resource2 = new Resource();
        resource2.setCode(source.getResourceCd2());
        resource2.setDescription(source.getResourceDesc2());
        resources.add(resource2);

        Resource resource3 = new Resource();
        resource3.setCode(source.getResourceCd3());
        resource3.setDescription(source.getResourceDesc3());
        resources.add(resource3);

        Resource resource4 = new Resource();
        resource4.setCode(source.getResourceCd4());
        resource4.setDescription(source.getResourceDesc4());
        resources.add(resource4);

        Resource resource5 = new Resource();
        resource5.setCode(source.getResourceCd5());
        resource5.setDescription(source.getResourceDesc5());
        resources.add(resource5);

        return resources;
    }

}
```